# URI IsWellFormedOriginalString for URL with hashbang

Tags: c#, validation, uri

I want to validate URL using `IsWellFormedOriginalString`. I use this code:

```
var enc2 = "/discussion/somepage.aspx?DiscussionID=13&PostID=1#post4";
Uri.TryCreate(enc2, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out u1);
Console.WriteLine(u1.IsWellFormedOriginalString());
```

But it returns `false`. If I use URL without hash

```
/discussion/somepage.aspx?DiscussionID=13&PostID=1
```

it works OK. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reaidng this article https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/ I realized that hash shouldn't be validated as a part of Uri. So I exclude hash part before check:

```
enc2 = enc2.Split('#')[0];
```